# Neo4j with algorithms

Tags: java, neo4j, graphchi

I am trying to decide which platform to use for a project I am working on and was wondering if anybody had some input.  I have a set of really large data (about 5 million rows long) and want to be able to run an algorithm on it.  I already developed a java program which works on small data by using sparse matrices and am having trouble scaling up.  I am also going to be wanting to visualize it later on, since the algorithm uses bipartite graphing methods to cluster my data.  I am looking into neo4j as platforms to use but am unsure if I would be able to do the computations or not. So my question is really how complex of an algorithm can Neo4j handle?  Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: your question is a bit vague. what are you looking for in an answer? 5 million doesn't seem that big--it should all fit in memory, for example, in a reasonable server, using neo4j. neo4j has a bunch of built-in algorithms (which also serve as examples for custom algorithms): https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/tree/2.0/community/graph-algo/src/main/java/org/neo4j/graphalgo/impl

Comment: 5 million would be the smallest instance.  The algorithm that I want to run on it involves putting the data into sparse matrices and multiplying/running loops on it until it converges.  Do you think I could recreate that in neo4j or would it be better to just look at using something like Graphchi instead?